# После выхода приложения в апсторе, перестали работать PUSH уведомления

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Тестировали приложение в режиме разработки. Создавали для этого сертификат development. На сервере загружали ssl сертификат. И всё работало. Приложение передавало токен устройства, а сервер отправлял пуш. 
А когда дело дошло до публикации, перевели приложение в режим distribution, и теперь на сервере уже сертификат для продакшен версии. Но пуши теперь не приходят. Приложение уже месяц в сторе, а пуши не работают. В чём может быть причина? Было у кого-нибудь так?

Comment: Вы используете свой сервер для отправки? Или же пользуетесь другими сервисами? Для APNS есть два разных линка, один для дев версии другой для продакшена, убедитесь, что ваш релиз билд использует верный линк. P.S. линк указывается на сервере

Comment: Вот даже не поленился и нашел Вам ссылки :) dev - gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195
release - gateway.push.apple.com 2195

Comment: @VitaliEller да линк был не тот. Но после смены на ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 пуши всё равно не приходит. Так же я ещё для тестирования пробовал приложение APN Tester Free, я там вводил токен полученный с устройства и сертификат, так же ставил галочку AdHoc/Production, но пуши тоже не приходят.

Comment: Хотя вот когда уже прошло много времени после смены линка на правильный, наконец-то стали приходить пуши. Видимо нужно было время.

Comment: Добавил как ответ. Рад что все заработало!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для APNS есть два разных `link-a`, один для `dev` версии другой для `release`, убедитесь, что ваш `release build` использует верный `link`.

```
dev - gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195 
release - gateway.push.apple.com 2195
```

Так же довольно хороший [инструмент](https://github.com/nomad/houston) для тестирвоания `push notifications`